# How to finish multiple activity in flutter when user open one activity?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been try like this, but just finish one previous activity

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
new MaterialPageRoute(settings: const RouteSettings(name: '/Group'), 
                    builder: (context) => new Group(i)));
```

How I can finish multiple previous activity when open one activity? thanks

Comment: there is no "finish" in flutter (as in andoird), navigation is like a stack with `push` and `pop` methods (just like fragments in android)

Comment: Can you tell me your use case, how do you want to navigate to Group page and from where?